# Typescript tuple to object type

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a tuple type like this:

```js
type Test<T extends string, V> = { type: T, value: V };
type Tuple = [
    Test<'string', string>, 
    Test<'number', number>, 
    Test<'integer', number>
];
```

From the type `Tuple` I would like to generate the type

```js
type TupleObject = {
    string: string,
    number: number,
    integer: number,
};
```

Is this at all possible and if so, how? So far I have only managed to get

```js
type TupleObject = {
    string: string | number,
    number: string | number,
    integer: string | number,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapped type with an as clause and map over `Tuple[number]`

```
type TupleToObject<T extends Array<Test<string, any>>> = {
    [K in T[number] as K['type']]: K['value']
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwA8MoQB7AgOwCbykQCcBLbAcwBooA1APigF4oBvKUSALlmoDcBDADYBXCNxpQAvgG4AsACgO0GMLCDozANoKou2AmQByYmXKHqJinWo69cREkPZhAWwBGEIuajP3n61C2uvZGZFjknt6+HkR0CgC6cvIKSrCq6jAA9gDybgBWEADGyKgYWHgEAIJERPwgKAZIllRQ-NggdJ1MrEFQmgDSUGSwmtGe8a0E-ZqGSobx8dzThgIiEPMKkgop4MrpELkFxd0qahBZh0Ul+3HyAPR3elAAegD82-ePqafql8UATN0WAoHk9CMBSBRuM1KCDHk8xkRuIjYZ8wWEIBEkT5XDFUaCZEA)